# Gate to gate electronic device usage on AmericanConnection/Chautauqua Airlines?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, electronic-items, american-airlines

I recently booked a flight that's on AmericanConnection, operated by Chautauqua Airlines. I know all American Airlines and American Eagle operated flights now allow gate-to-gate usage of portable electronic devices, but back when they announced this they specifically exempted third-party airlines. Has that changed, or do they still make you turn off devices above/below 10,000 feet?

Comment: Can you provide link that exempts third-party airlines?

Comment: @Karlson - a basic version of it is right in the quote that you posted as "This change won't be implemented on some of American's regional flights (operated as American Eagle) until later this year." However, Kate's quote doesn't even say that the policy change applies to AmericanConnection, and Chautauqua Airlines was specifically listed as "later that year."

Comment: I am not sure I follow what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to report - American Connection/Chautauqua Airlines does indeed allow personal electronic device usage from gate-to-gate.

Thanks to everyone else for chiming in!

Answer (score 3):

The [announcement from AA](http://hub.aa.com/en/nr/pressrelease/american-airlines-customers-will-have-gate-to-gate-use-of-handheld-portable-electronic-devices-beginning-this-afternoon) mentions "American's entire mainline fleet as well as regional aircraft operated by American Eagle Airlines." I suspect this is simply because those are the planes they control. AA doesn't specifically announce that you can use your devices on United flights, since they can't control United, but of course you can, since what all these airlines are doing is adapting to a change in the overall rules from the FAA.

Apparently this is something that needs to happen airline by airline. [An NBC news article](http://www.nbcnews.com/business/travel/which-airlines-now-allow-electronic-devices-f8C11551554) summarized the status in Nov 2013, including:

> American Airlines on Nov. 4 said the new rules apply to "American's entire mainline fleet as well as regional aircraft operated by American Eagle Airlines." However, it does not yet apply to American Eagle flights operated by SkyWest Airlines, ExpressJet Airlines, Republic Airline or Chautauqua Airlines, American spokesman Matt Miller told CNBC.

Comment: Right, I saw the November announcement all over the place, but was hoping for something a little more definite. Worst case I'll find out when I fly, but I like to be fully prepared with the right gadgets in the right bags ahead of time ;)

Answer (score 2):

From the [press release from FAA](http://www.faa.gov/news/press_releases/news_story.cfm?newsId=15254) the rules have been relaxed and the airlines can implement their own policies allowing use of personal electronic devices below 10000 feet.

[American Airlines](https://www.aa.com/i18n/travelInformation/duringFlight/onboardTechnology.jsp) and American Eagle implemented or will implement this policy by the end of 2013 or in 2014.

> Good news! You're now able to read your e-books, play games, and watch videos on your portable electronic devices from gate to gate within the U.S. There are a few things to keep in mind during taxi, takeoff and landing:
>
> - Devices will need to be in airplane mode and you'll need to secure them by either holding or placing them under your seat.
> - Wi-Fi access on equipped aircraft will be available shortly after takeoff
> - This change doesn't apply to larger items such as laptops. Those items will still need to be stowed.
>
> This change won't be implemented on some of American's regional flights (operated as American Eagle) until later this year. Because the safety of our customers and people is always our top priority, you should still listen to all safety briefings and comply with crewmember instructions.

So since [Chautauqua](http://www.flychautauqua.com/Flying_with_us/COC.aspx) is a contracted party for the individual airline such as [American](http://www.aa.com/i18n/customerService/customerCommitment/conditionsOfCarriage.jsp) they are subject to American Airlines contract of carriage and PED policy irrespective of them being a separate company.

Comment: I agree they should be bound by the contract of carriage, but the PED policy is not part of that.  As far as I know, Chautauqua is in fact a separate airline and thus responsible for its own safety practices, and I'd expect the PED policy to fall under that.  (By their contract with AA, they paint "American" on their planes and have AA sell their tickets, but the operation of the flight is up to Chautauqua.)

Comment: The key is that the **operating** carrier has to certify with the FAA before they can modify their electronic device policies. Chautauqua and the other Republic holdings had to certify separately from American and American Eagle. Good to hear from others that this has been achieved.